# Multiple inconsistent JNI DETECTED ERRORS IN APPLICATION built using Xamarin Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, xamarin, cross-platform

I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017 and coding in C# using a PCL project. I am currently facing an issue whereby my app crashes most of the time and occasionally it can run without errors. However, I am not sure what causes this and need help. Below shows a snippet of one of the errors I got.

```
12482): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x200001 (should be 0x1)
07-06 14:02:49.923 F/art     (12482): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x200001
```

After cleaning and rebuilding the my droid code, I get this error

```
 07-06 13:52:48.094 F/art     (11846): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jclass has wrong type: java.lang.String
07-06 13:52:48.094 F/art     (11846): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     in call to CallStaticObjectMethod
07-06 13:52:48.094 F/art     (11846): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] "Thread-13" prio=5 tid=19 Runnable
07-06 13:52:48.094 F/art     (11846): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d95790 self=0x7f7bba9800
07-06 13:52:48.094 F/art     (11846): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | sysTid=11881 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f79f46450
07-06 13:52:48.094 F/art     (11846): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | state=R schedstat=( 33691566 9679324 130 ) utm=3 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
07-06 13:52:48.094 F/art     (11846): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | stack=0x7f79d48000-0x7f79d4a000 stackSize=2045KB
07-06 13:52:48.094 F/art     (11846): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

After cleaning and rebuilding my PCL I get back the first error. Does anyone have any idea what may have gone wrong from these logs?